# Wait for any task to finish, then start a new one

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm wondering how could I, without doing my own implementation of reporting using blocking queues and similar, as easily as possible implement the following scenario:

I have K * N tasks, every batch of N tasks is a bit different.

1. Submit the first batch of N tasks (the work is done concurrently on every task)
2. When any of the tasks finishes submit a new one (taking it from the second batch)

The second point is repeated until all of the tasks are finished.

Should I use a CyclicBarrier and submit a task when there's one thread waiting? I guess I'd have to use a blocking queue to guarantee that I won't submit the same task twice.

Comment: Use a fixed thread pool `Executor`...See [the Executors trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) for more details

Comment: So, a fixed thread pool executor guarantees order? edit: seems it does, thanks!

Comment: In the sense that each task is executed in the order it was put in, AFAIK, yes, but remember, tasks may finish in different orders.  You can also use (if I recall correctly) `submitAll` which will return a `List` of `Future`, which is guaranteed to be in the same order as the elements you submitted...

Comment: Yep, I do have that in mind, if I were ever to constrain that 3rd batch can't start if all of the tasks from the 1st didn't finish, I'd have to use a barrier with some counting state, right?
Thanks for the extra hint, although, I don't need the order as results are collected in a queue of its own.

Comment: To give you an exact solution it would probably be wise if we knew how the tasks were related to eachother, if at all.. Though generally @MadProgrammer 's solution is the one to go for.

Comment: They can all be created independent of each other. It's just that batches are colored, and I don't want the first batch to mix with third, second with fourth, and so forth. (mixing means running at the same time)

Comment: @Looft,  There isn't really a thing called "fixed thread pool executor."  The function, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)` creates a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` that is configured with `corePoolSize == maximumPoolSize` and, with an unbounded `BlockingQueue`.  It's the queue implementation, not the ThreadPoolExecutor that determines the order in which the tasks will be performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be sure that the first batch does not mix with the third (and so forth), you could have a CountDownLatch for each batch initialized with the number of tasks in  a batch, and the tasks within a batch should await() on the latch corresponding to the batch N - 2, and when a task is finished, it can call countDown() on its corresponding latch.